# Combining Two SQL Queries with different where and returning unique rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine these 2 SQL queries.

```
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `ID` = 56

SELECT * FROM `live` WHERE `ID` = 56 AND `ACTIVE` = 0 AND t1.`Shown` = 'complete'
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM `history` t1
JOIN `live` t2
ON t1.`ID` = 56 AND t1.`ACTIVE` = 0 AND t1.`Shown` = 'complete'
WHERE t2.`ID` = 56
```

But the query above results in selecting everything from `live` and forgetting about `history`.

**Expected result:** I expect to select all columns from `history` and  `live` where the `ID is equal to 56`. But there will be scenarios where the `ID's` in `history` don't exist in `live` -- in which case I want to select all from `history` where the `ID` is equal.

Both tables have different columns. The only thing that they have in common is the `ID`.

**Solution:**

`Using UNION with specific columns from both tables.`

Comment: How do you want to combine the two queries?  What is the table structure of `history` and `live` ?

Comment: You need to show us some sample data and expected output.  It isn't clear whether you should be joining or attempting to take a `UNION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `history` and `live` tables have the same number (and preferably type) of columns, then a `UNION` query might be what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `ID` = 56
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `live` WHERE `ID` = 56 AND `ACTIVE` = 0 AND t1.`Shown` = 'complete'
```

If the number of columns are not the same, then you can choose the same number of columns from both tables to make the query work.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM `live` t1
JOIN `history` t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.`ID` = 56 AND t1.`ACTIVE` = 0 AND t1.`Shown` = 'complete'
```

But I guess you should describe your problem with some more details...

Comment: I think it's because some ID's in live might not exist, while they exist in history.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both tables have the same columns, it sounds like you want to use a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) here.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
    FROM history 
    WHERE ID = 56
UNION
SELECT Col1, Col2, ..., ColN
    FROM live
    WHERE ID = 56 
        AND ACTIVE = 0 
        AND Shown = 'complete'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `history` and `live` have same then  have the same number (and preferably type) of columns then this could help you

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `ID` = 56
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `live` WHERE `ID` = 56 AND `ACTIVE` = 0 AND t1.`Shown` = 'complete'
) as result
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM
history h JOIN live l ON
h.id = l.id 
WHERE h.id = 56 AND l.id= 56 AND l.`ACTIVE` = 0 AND l.`Shown` = 'complete'
```